# How do I unassociate executables with wine?

Tags: wine, file-association, lubuntu

I want to un-associate executables to open with wine, for security reasons

I'm using Lubuntu 11.10, how can I do this?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Right click on .exe file> under properties> opens with> select the application> add or remove.

Make your selection then close.